# How to disable IntelliJs method name replacement

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ 12.0.4 I find it very annoying that when I type a method name (for a new method that doesn't exist) that resembles a method name that does exist, when I type "()" IntelliJ replaces the manually typed out name with the name of the prexisting method.  This is most frustrating when I'm TDDing as I'm writing out my "thoughts" into the test and then I use the auto generation to create the missing methods.

For example

```
public class SomeTest() {
    public void myTest() {
        /*
         * Upon typing ( IntelliJ replaces the method call with givenAFooBar()
         */
        givenAFoo();
    }

    private FooBar givenAFooBar() { return new FooBar(); }
}
```

How can I disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug that is already fixed, you can [download IDEA 12.1 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12.1+EAP) build and try it.

Comment: It is indeed fixed in 12.1